# Is it possible to set perfectly rounded elements size?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have tried setting element size manually to ie. 1000px or 1015px etc.
1000px is exactly 1000px on dev tools, but 1015 or something similar is never exaclty the same, always looks like 1014,98999. Tried setting element sizes with rounding in jS, but the same situation. Element sizes still were with numbers after " , ". Rounded numbers were perfect without any number after " , ".

So my question. Is it even possible to have exactly rounded element size number without manually setting it to 1000, 500, 200px?

```js
const Board = document.getElementById('Game_board')
const BodySize = [document.querySelector('body').getBoundingClientRect().width, document.querySelector('body').getBoundingClientRect().height]
const roundedBodySize = [Math.round(BodySize[0]), Math.round(BodySize[1])]
const BoardSize = [Math.round(roundedBodySize[0] * 0.75), Math.round(roundedBodySize[1] * 0.75)]

Board.style.width = (Math.round(BoardSize[0])) + 'px'
Board.style.height = BoardSize[1] + 'px'
Board.style.position = 'absolute'
Board.style.top = 12.5 + '%'
Board.style.left = 12.5 + '%'
```

```css
body,
head {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: black;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#Game_board {
  background-color: darkgrey;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Platform Jumper</title>
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='styles.css'>
  <script defer src='script.js'></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="Game_board"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can't reproduce? Also why in the world are you applying styles to the head element?

Comment: That was a mistake which i just did not deleted. When im just setting element size manually to ie. 1015 px, in dev tools it says 1014,989... px, but setting it to 1000px shows exactly 1000px

Comment: I'm confused about what you are trying to achieve here. Are you wanting to set an aspect ratio on an element, or a maximum height/width?

Comment: Just element sizes like width and height but without numbers after " , " which are always there when setting size like 1015px so element is never accurate

Comment: Try setting the zoom on your browser to 100%.

Comment: What dev tools are you using? What browser? More importantly, why does it matter? Sub-pixel rendering is a thing.

Comment: Opera built-in dev tools. Just tried do some if statements which required exact numbers, but figured it out. And also some curiosity why 1015 is not rounded when 1000 is

Answer (score 0):

This works fine.  What's the problem?
[image]

```css
div{
height:1015px;
width:1015px;
background-color:blue;
}
```

```html
<div>
</div>
```

Comment: height 1014.99px
width 1014.99px

in dev tools

Never rounded numbers

Comment: check the screen shot I just added.  This shows exactly 1015px height and width,  You are doing something else with your code to cause the problem

Comment: Maybe there is something on my opera or even PC but even checked the same thing as you and still 1014.99px

Comment: what happens when you check this snippet in developer tools on your machine?  Are you seeing 1015px as I do?

Comment: Nope, width and height 1014.99px. But as i thought it's only opera. On chrome it shows 1015 px on  both

Comment: well, seems like your machine then.  Unable to reproduce problem. Firefox, Chrome and edge all show 1015px